# Speech Synthesize API no longer working properly

Tags: php, text-to-speech, speech, speech-synthesis

The speech synthesizer API seems to be only working for English. Is it just me? Am I doing something wrong in the code? Or is it not working for anyone else? For some languages like Chinese, and Japanese, it doesn't output any sounds at all, and for languages like Spanish and others, it just reads them like how it reads the regular English language. This just started happening recently, maybe for the past 2 weeks or so? Before the same exact code worked fine.

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function() {

  //te amo <--- spanish
  // 我爱你 <--- chinese

  var speech = "我爱你";
  document.write(speech);
  var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(speech);

  u.lang = "zh-CN";
  u.volume = 1; //0-1 1=default
  u.rate = 0.5; //0-10, 1=default
  u.pitch = 1.9; //0-2 1=default

  window.speechSynthesis.speak(u);

});

</script>
```

**For Reference:**

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-speech-synthesis-api

```
"arabic" => "ar-DZ",
"bulgarian" => "bg",
"catalan" => "ca",
"chinese-simplified" => "zh-CN",
"chinese-traditional" => "zh-CN",
"czech" => "cs",
"danish" => "da",
"dutch" => "nl-BE",
"english" => "en-US",
"estonian" => "et",
"finnish" => "fi",
"french" => "fr-BE",
"german" => "de-AT",
"greek" => "el",
"haitian-creole" => "en-US",
"hebrew" => "he",
"hindi" => "hi",
"hungarian" => "hu",
"indonesian" => "id",
"italian" => "it-IT",
"japanese" => "ja",
"klingon" => "en-US",
"korean" => "ko",
"latvian" => "lv",
"lithuanian" => "lt",
"malay" => "ms-BN",
"maltese" => "mt",
"norwegian" => "no-NO",
"persian" => "fa",
"polish" => "pl",
"portuguese" => "pt-BR",
"romanian" => "ro-MO",
"russian" => "ru",
"slovak" => "sk",
"slovenian" => "sl",
"spanish" => "es-AR",
"swedish" => "sv-FI",
"thai" => "th",
"turkish" => "tr",
"ukrainian" => "uk",
"urdu" => "ur",
"vietnamese" => "vi",
"welsh" => "cy",
```

Comment: we are not the support department for this, or any, API. go ask them

Comment: @Dagon Is there a stackoverflow section for API?